# See if object exists | Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to make a anticheat that kicks the player if they destroy objects on the map I tried this but it did nothing

```lua
for i,v in pairs(workspace.Doors:GetChildren()) do
   if v.Parent == nil then
      game.Players.LocalPlayer:Kick("Kicked for cheating.")
   end
end
```

and yes this is a localscript

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks as if it is looping through what the client sees, then checking if it is a nil value. As the local-side `GetChildren()` will loop through what the client can see, it isn't going to find whether or not the object exists as it won't loop through. I'd recommend creating a table variable of every door name that should exist (example: `local Doors = {"Door1", "Door", "Door3", "Door4"}`) and have each door named to a unique name. Then when looping through, add the checked door name to another table (in this case I will call it `CheckedDoors`) and after looping, check if every door in `Doors` is in `CheckedDoors` using `table.find()` and if not then kick.